Confusion related to Jhanas' involvement on the path
I have a two-part question. One is related to personal practice and the other is scriptural or theoretical.
I'll lay down a concise personal background for the sake of clarity. I am an irregular practitioner of Vipassana. I have finished 3 Vipassana retreats (Goenka tradition). I try to meditate for 2 hours a day most days. I also attempt walking and sleeping meditation as much as I can at times when I'm not formally meditating.
Question 1
It had been difficult for me to establish equanimity in body scanning since i was getting distracted too often. So I allowed myself to indulge in just doing anapana sati (samatha meditation).
While I thought I was just doing anapana sati, I probably unconsciously was doing insight meditation too by using the nostrils as the object (I'm not sure if that's what it is, please correct me if I'm wrong).
I would try to attain equanimity towards the sensations within my nostrils. My breath would increase pace when i would fail to get the sensation. I would then try to slow it down to natural pace which is super subtle, by attempting to be equanimous about the CURRENT sensations and eliminating all cravings.
When i would succeed, the breathing would become too subtle, too short, too sharp and too fast to notice and yet I'd be effortlessly noticing it without affecting the pace of the breath. At this point I would experience the below mentioned state.
I'm not sure if this state is the first jhana or not but it's the most significant experience I've had as of yet while formally meditating. It has following characteristics:

a feeling that breathing (the area of nostrils) is the handle through which the instrument of my whole body is being held with
a uniform sense of numbness throughout the body
a steady awareness of  the non-uniform subtle sensations on the body yet simultaneously uniform and unbroken sense of equanimity towards all of the sensations
the feeling of "MY body" being retracted/sinking within the objective body as if the ME is far away from the surface of the body
a mild pleasure arising from the realization of the momentary freedom from surface sensations

Note: I've experienced this state multiple times but usually when it occurs, i get taken by surprise and either get too excited about it or anxious about the possibility of it ending, in both cases it actually does end up terminating the state.
Q: Is this any of the rupa jhanas or am I just experiencing normal precursor stages before entering the first jhana?
Question 2
I've been obsessively delving into Buddhist literature through various PDFs, forums such as this and meditation related subreddits as of late. I haven't formally studied the canon. So please forgive my ignorance.
I read somewhere (I don't recall where) that if one progresses through the arupa Jhanas (Samadhi) without making any progress in the insight (Panna) then after death, the citta is reborn in the formless realm (arupa loka) and has to stay there for a long, long time until the pleasant sankharas run out after which one returns to the material realm whence one can continue the journey towards liberation through insight practice.
Q:
is it true that too much progress in Samadhi and little progress in Panna can lead to rebirth in arupa/deva/brahma loka which would actually delay the progress towards liberation?
if it's true, then how farther would it be safe to progress in jhanas to secure rebirth in human realm so that one can keep working towards nibbana?
Thank you for your patience! Much metta!


Goenka tradition

The instructions in the Pali Suttas are not the same as Goenka

body scanning

The Pali suttas do not instruct body scanning.

anapanasati

mindfulness with breathing is a complete practice in the Pali Suttas (rather than a preliminary practice) - refer to MN 118, SN 54.8 and SN 54.11

anapana sati (samatha meditation)

Anapanasati results in both samatha & vipassana. For example, if the respective in & out breaths are clearly experienced as impermanent (anicca), this is vipassana. If it is clearly experienced the body breathes (anatta) rather than the 'self' breathes, this is vipassana.

My breath would increase pace when i would fail to get the sensation

The increase in breath pace is due to mental worry & craving. It is another aspect of vipassana (insight experience of cause & effect) to see clearly how the state of mind affects the state of the breathing. The lust & anxiety towards meditation caused the pace of the breathing to increase & the length of the breathing to shorten.

I would then try to slow it down to natural pace which is super subtle, by attempting to be equanimous about the CURRENT sensations and eliminating all cravings. When i would succeed, the breathing would become too subtle, too short, too sharp and too fast to notice...

If the mind has equanimity, the breathing should naturally become longer, smoother & more refined rather than shorter & faster.

I'm not sure if this state is the first jhana

This is surely not the first jhana. The first jhana is an exalted heavenly 'superhuman' state.

a uniform sense of numbness throughout the body

Developing anapanasati results in lucidity throughout the body

a steady awareness of the non-uniform subtle sensations on the body yet simultaneously uniform and unbroken sense of equanimity towards all of the sensations

This sounds OK & should be developed.

the feeling of "MY body" being retracted/sinking within the objective body as if the ME is far away from the surface of the body

Do not be concerned about such experiences. This concern & mental pondering is a loss of unbroken sense of equanimity.

a mild pleasure arising from the realization of the momentary freedom from surface sensations

There must also be equanimity towards any pleasurable feelings.

either get too excited about it or anxious about the possibility of it ending, in both cases it actually does end up terminating the state.

Yes, it ends up terminating the state. The purpose of Buddhist meditation is to train in & to receive the pleasurable rewards of equanimity, non-craving & non-attachment. As soon as there is attachment, there will be tension & stress. The entire purpose of Buddhist meditation is to abandon excitement & anxiety. The numerous Anapanasati & Satipatthana suttas say countless times:

Herein (in this teaching) a monk lives contemplating the body in the
body, ardent, clearly comprehending and mindful, having overcome, in
this world, covetousness (excitement) and grief (anxiety); he lives contemplating feelings in
feelings, ardent, clearly comprehending and mindful, having overcome,
in this world, covetousness and grief; he lives contemplating
consciousness in consciousness, ardent, clearly comprehending and
mindful, having overcome, in this world, covetousness and grief; he
lives contemplating mental objects in mental objects, ardent, clearly
comprehending and mindful, having overcome, in this world,
covetousness and grief.
MN 10

In conclusion, nothing of what has been experienced is close to jhana. Simply the thought of 'jhana' is another attachment born from craving. The Buddha taught jhana is reached by making "letting go" the object of meditation.

There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, making it his object to let go, attains concentration, attains singleness of mind. Quite withdrawn from sensuality, withdrawn from unskillful mental qualities, he enters & remains in the first jhana...
SN 48.10


The idea of 'rebirth' is another obstacle to meditation, because it creates 'self-view' craving & worry. MN 2 says:

This is how he attends unwisely: ‘Was I in the past? Was I not in the
past? What was I in the past? How was I in the past? Having been what,
what did I become in the past? Shall I be in the future? Shall I not
be in the future? What shall I be in the future? How shall I be in the
future? Having been what, what shall I become in the future?’ Or else
he is inwardly perplexed about the present thus: ‘Am I? Am I not? What
am I? How am I? Where has this being come from? Where will it go?’
“When he attends unwisely in this way, one of six views arises in him.
The view ‘self exists for me’ arises in him as true and established;
or the view ‘no self exists for me’ arises in him as true and
established; or the view ‘I perceive self with self’ arises in him as
true and established; or the view ‘I perceive not-self with self’
arises in him as true and established; or the view ‘I perceive self
with not-self’ arises in him as true and established; or else he has
some such view as this: ‘It is this self of mine that speaks and feels
and experiences here and there the result of good and bad actions; but
this self of mine is permanent, everlasting, eternal, not subject to
change, and it will endure as long as eternity.’ This speculative
view, bhikkhus, is called the thicket of views, the wilderness of
views, the contortion of views, the vacillation of views, the fetter
of views. Fettered by the fetter of views, the untaught ordinary
person is not freed from birth, ageing, and death, from sorrow,
lamentation, pain, grief, and despair; he is not freed from suffering,
I say.
MN 2

There are English language translations of Pali suttas that say both rupa & arupa jhana without wisdom result in 'rebirth' as a 'god' and also later into 'hell', such as:

There is the case where an individual, withdrawn from sensuality,
withdrawn from unskillful qualities, enters & remains in the first
jhana: rapture & pleasure born from withdrawal, accompanied by
directed thought & evaluation. He savors that, longs for that, finds
satisfaction through that. Staying there—fixed on that, dwelling there
often, not falling away from that—then when he dies he reappears in
conjunction with the devas of Brahma’s retinue. The devas of Brahma’s
retinue, monks, have a life-span of an eon. A run-of-the-mill person
having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas,
goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades.
But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up
all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of
being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the
distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones
and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination,
a reappearing.
AN 4.123

However, there are also Pali suttas translated to say wisdom leads to godly realms, such as:

Take a person who, quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful qualities, enters and remains in the first absorption …
They contemplate the phenomena there—included in form, feeling, perception, choices, and consciousness—as impermanent, as suffering, as diseased, as a boil, as a dart, as misery, as an affliction, as alien, as falling apart, as empty, as not-self. When their body breaks up, after death, they’re reborn in the company of the gods of the pure abodes (suddhāvāsānaṁ devānaṁ). This rebirth (upapatti ) is not shared with ordinary people.
AN 4.124

The word 'upapatti' literally means 'attainment' and the word 'deva' does not always literally refer to a 'god'.

